# rml reports in openerp

Tags: python, report, odoo, rml

I use Openerp 6.0.I have a date field named x_podate in account.invoice form.In account_print_invoice report form i call the date field using the following code:

```
    <td>
      <para style="terp_default_6">[[ o.x_podate ]]</para>
    </td>
```

and it shows the date value entered. But the problem is when the datefield is not supplied with any value the repot print out shows as False.Can someone suggest any solution for this am i missing something?

Comment: Dear PrAvItHa,
I'm also new to OpenERP Reports.u recommend rml or jasper.
please let me know steps for that.?
i don't know wats da place for start my code.

धन्यवाद यू

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can type in Python code between the square brackets, and then you can take advantage of [Python's evaluation rules for boolean expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_2.6/Boolean_Expressions). So if you want to display an empty string if `o.x_podate` is not provided, use `[[ o.x_podate or "" ]]`.